# Angular PWA Firebase login fail

Tags: angular, firebase, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

When I turn off the service worker everything is working but when I turn on the service worker Firebase Auth throws 504 Gateway timeout error!

Here is an ngsw-gonfig.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "urls": [
        "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/*"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 20,
        "maxAge": "1h",
        "timeout": "6s"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the error message, something related to service worker configuration but not sure what's wong.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at DataGroup.safeFetch (ngsw-worker.js:851:27)
    at DataGroup.handleFetch (ngsw-worker.js:708:23)
    at async AppVersion.handleFetch (ngsw-worker.js:924:20)
    at async Driver.handleFetch (ngsw-worker.js:1432:19)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried serving the PWA over https?

Comment: Yes I tried, but the same issue :(

Comment: What if you remove the `dataGroups` entry in your `ngsw-gonfig.json`?